# Rigify issue, cannot move controls

Tags: modeling

I have an issue with rigify, when I create a human armature, and then I click on generate button to generate the controls, and after that I click on any of the curve controls, it always selects the whole thing, as if it's combined or locked, is that a bug? I cannot control anything like that, let alone to skin any mesh with it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I had to press CTRL+Tab in order to enter pose mode and now I can use the controls finally.